# Error installing RPI.gpio

Tags: gpio, pi-3, rpi.gpio, software-installation, minibian

I'm a new enthusiast trying to learn with raspberry pi so I apologize if I don't use the correct programming terms...

The problem that i'm having at the moment is that when I try `pip install rpi-gpio` i get the following error:

```
unable to execute 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc': No such file or directory

error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /var/working/venv/bin/python2 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-7BUUIX/rpi.gpio/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-x_nNzV record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /var/working/venv/include/site/python2.7 failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-7BUUIX/rpi.gpio
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
-------------------------------------------------
```

I'm using minibian as the operative system, I have already installed `apt-get install python2.7-dev`

I'm on a Pi3

EDIT_01: I have tried to `apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf` and I get this error: 
E: Unable to locate package gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf

[image]

EDIT_02: I tried manual installation of RPi.GPIO and I'm getting an error when I try to run `sudo python RPi.GPIO-0.6.3/setup.py`

ERROR

```
    sudo python RPi.GPIO-0.6.3/setup.py Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "RPi.GPIO-0.6.3/setup.py", line 40, in <module> 
long_description = open('README.txt').read() + open('CHANGELOG.txt').read(), IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.txt''
```

It somehow doesn't find the README.txt file but I checked and It was succesfully extracted from the download.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Please take the [tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [helpcenter](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help) to see how things work here.

Comment: You've got three answers and some suggestions. Did you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf
sudo apt-get install python-dev python3-dev
sudo pip install rpi-gpio
```

Edit1: Just noticed your using minibian - what is the reason for this ?

Edit2: Added 'install gcc...'

Comment: hey thanks for replying! I'm using minibian because i'm following a very basic tutorial I found online that uses this operative system... 
basically they told me to install minibian and I did it without questioning anything.

I just tried your suggestion and I'm still getting the same error. 

what is the meaning of unable to execute 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc': No such file or directory

error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1?

Comment: Its trying to use a c compiler which it can't find. Can you post a link to the tutorial your following. I would always recommend the Raspbian operating system to new users.

Comment: Edited my answer - this is a guess !

Comment: Thanks for your help, I appreciate it!

Here is the link: https://www.udemy.com/rpi-full-stack/

As soon as I arrive home I will try it out, thank you!

Comment: You may be better off using [Raspbian lite](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) - there's a lot more support for the "official" distro than there is third-party things like minibian

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf and I'm getting this error: E: Unable to locate package gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf

Answer (score 0):

May manual installation work for you. You have to follow steps shown below.

**Step-1:Download the library**

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/e2/58/6e1b775606da6439fa3fd1550e7f714ac62aa75e162eed29dbec684ecb3e/RPi.GPIO-0.6.3.tar.gz
```

**step-2: Extract the archive to new directory**

```
tar -xvf RPi.GPIO-0.6.3.tar.gz
```

**Step-3: Browse to the new directory**

```
cd RPi.GPIO-0.6.3
```

**Step-4:  Install the library**

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

**Step-5: Remove the directory and archive file**

```
cd ~ 
sudo rm -rf RPi.GPIO-0.*
```

***Note: You should take care about step-2 and step-3. Since I have no idea about the tar.gz file gets downloaded into which directory.***

Comment: Hey, thanks for the alternative.
Somehow I managed to do everything you suggested but I'm getting an error on STEP 4:
root@intemperie:~/RPI_GPIO# sudo python RPi.GPIO-0.6.3/setup.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RPi.GPIO-0.6.3/setup.py", line 40, in <module>
    long_description = open('README.txt').read() + open('CHANGELOG.txt').read(),
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.txt'' '

Comment: Read the INSTALL.txt file on the tar archive.Definitely you will get some idea about installing RPi.GPIO. You can try step-4 edited above. Also you can try $ sudo pip install RPi.GPIO instead $ sudo pip install rpi.gpio

Comment: @fedezorrozuag I checked your edit and screenshot on the question now. You are tried to install(using step-4) immediately after extracting tar file(on step-2). This won't work and Pi will verbose like "There os no such file or directory". Since you are missed step-3 you got above error. You have to now browse to RPi.GPIO_0.6.3 directory using cd command and perform step-4 and step-5. Or you can start from step-1 after deleting tar.gz file and corresponding archive from the directory you are currently working.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your replies to others, you mentioned you are using minibian.

Originally you have the error

> unable to execute 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc': No such file or directory
>
> error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1

and you tried unsuccessfully to

> apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf

but the package could not be located.

Do this after you ssh into your minibian

> apt-get update
>
> apt-get install build-essential

then go to wherever your working directory is and start your virtual environment

> cd /var/working
>
> . venv/bin/activate

and try again with the rpi.gpio install and it should now work for you, as it did for me.

> pip install rpi.gpio